# Expression for the variance of the slope between two measurements

Tags: variance, error-propagation

Let's say we measure two points $S_1$ and $S_2$, at $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively. $S_1$ and $S_2$ are contaminated with Gaussian noise with standard deviation $\sigma$. We now want to calculate the slope a between $S_1$ and $S_2$. What is the expression for the variance of $a$?

I figured the following:
$$a= (S_2 - S_1)/(x_2 - x_1)$$
$$S_2 = a(x_2 - x_1) + S_1$$

So then the standard deviations of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are
$$\sigma _{S1} = \sigma$$
$$\sigma _{S2} = (a(x_2 - x_1) + S_1) \sigma)$$

The variance of $a$ is then given by
$$Var(a) = \frac{1}{(x_2 - x_1)^2}(\frac{Var(S_1)}{n_1} + \frac{Var(S_2)}{n_2})$$
$$= \frac{\sigma^2}{(x_2 - x_1)^2}(\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{a(x_2 - x_1)+S_1}{n_2})$$
Where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the number of measurements used to determine $S_1$ and $S_2$.

The standard deviation of $a$ would be given by
$$Sd(a) = \frac{\sigma}{(x_2 - x_1)}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{a(x_2 - x_1)+S_1}{n_2}}$$

Is this expression correct? Also, what would happen if we would take the log of $S_1$ and $S_2$ first?

Comment: It doesn't look right, because by the basic properties of variance (namely, bilinearity) $$\begin{aligned}\operatorname{Var}(a)& = \operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{S_2}{x_2-x_1}\right)+\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{-S_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{n_1^2(x_2-x_1)^2}\sigma^2 + \frac{(-1)^2}{n_2^2(x_2-x_1)^2}\sigma^2\\&= \frac{1}{(x_2-x_1)^2}\left(\frac{1}{n_2^2}+\frac{1}{n_1^2}\right)\sigma^2,\end{aligned}$$ which doesn't look much like your result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see. So rewriting the standard deviations of $S_1$ and $S_2$ is not the right way to go (or do I just do something wrong there?). Could you explain where the squares of $n_1^2$ and $n_2^2$ are coming from?

Comment: I have had to presume you meant the $n_i$ to represent the number of independent measurements of each quantity.  I should not have squared them, though -- my apologies.